# Floating toolbar component for ReactNative/ReactJS?

Tags: react-native

I'm figuring how to implement a floating toolbar like this.

[image]

It stays on top of the screen, but may become invisible/visible as user scrolls the screen. Is there any React Native/ReactJS component for this?

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the image shared .
I think you are looking for a component to display tooltip.

You can use **react-native-tooltip**.
To install run below command

```
npm install react-native-tooltip --save
```

For complete implimentation you can refer **[link](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-tooltip)**

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hmm sorry I guess I'm not clear enough. Just updated my image. Hopefully it reveals my intention better :)